# I want to create a Visual Recipe site on WordPress, any suggestions or tips on how i can do it?

Tags: drupal, joomla, wordpress

I would like to create a visual recipe site, which lists how to make a dish in step by step through pictures.. Is it possible to create a custom page template where I can the following fields.

1.Dishname(title)
2.Introduction(Brief info)
3.Ingredients
4.upload photo input..
followed by add more pic

Is it possible in Wordpress, you have any effective ideas? please share :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure it's possible. I recommend you to create a new custom post type 'recipe' And add custom fields as you please. This article should definitely get you started: http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/